# How do I connect to sql database from react?

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if anyone can show me how to connect my react app create with create-react-app to connect to a local mysql database. Is there any library out there that does this or do I have to start completely from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to build a server with API routes to query the data from your database.

Comment: But create-react-app comes with a server. Do I need to create a separate server for this task?

Comment: create-react-app comes with a webpack development server.

Comment: Yes. So I can just use that server?

Comment: Nah I don't believe you can actually edit that server, you would have to build out your own with API routes.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of backend  server script build with language such as php or nodejs that will create api endpoints to be consumed by your react scripts

Comment: But create-react-app comes with a server. Do I need to create a separate server for this task?