# Is it possible to integrate MySQL database to create-react-app project?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, mysql-workbench

I have a project based on ReactJS (create-react-app) and I want to import comments (localhost:3000/fullarticle) from mySQL (I added db content via "mySQL Workbench" software). But there is not a lot of information about it in the web, so I am not sure if it is a really good idea. What could you advice me? Thank you.

My project:
https://masa-sababa.herokuapp.com

GitHub page (it may be updated): https://github.com/thesiv95/masa-sababa

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript running in a web browser cannot directly make the raw network connections required to connect to MySQL.

> so I am not sure if it is a really good idea.

It's not a bad idea! Applications interact with databases all the time, so it's logical to want to do so.

You can integrate a React-based JavaScript application with any number of backend database layers, *but you'll need to employ an additional web service to do so*.

You can use JavaScript in the browser (your React application) to make and receive HTTP requests via [AJAX](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) to this additional service.

Typical implementations might use Node.js, but you could feasibly use any language/framework of your choice.

This is a solved problem, too. Make use of existing, powerful libraries such as [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) or [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and refer to the [React docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) as needed.

---

Potential duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54325397/705131), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59389062/705131) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42865650/705131).

The basic answer is: you'll need an API of some sort.

Here are some other, non-StackOverflow resources on the subject that may help you take the next step.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-the-create-react-app-with-a-Node-SQL-backend

https://dev.to/jerodimusprime/building-dynamic-react-apps-with-database-data-3apo

https://dev.to/kmaryam27/step-by-step-react-nodejs-and-mysql-simple-full-stack-application-2018-part-4-2bhg

https://github.com/stmoreau/React-Express-MySQL

https://medium.com/@carloscuba014/building-a-react-app-that-connects-to-mysql-via-nodejs-using-docker-a8acbb0e9788